# how to call Photoshop cs5 function from C#?

Tags: c#, photoshop

Making a winform in C#,there are several buttons, Click the button to achieve the photoshop cs5 functions through the ps'dll ? All I know is c# call cs4's functions through "interop.photoshop.dll", but I don't know which dll I should call in cs5. I can't find any info about c# in PS cs5 SDK,it't all about andriod,ios... Can anybody help me ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the Photoshop CS5 SDK with all documentation (including all on the COM interfaces) at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk/eula.html

It comes with samples/source code too...

Comment: I've downloaded the sdk, but it's all about andriod,ios , I can't find any info about .net

Comment: There is no .NET but there is COM which you can use with .NET !

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem 2 days ago

First, look here:
http://www.pcpix.com/Photoshop/

You must download script listener plugin for photoshop, then convert JS script to c# language.
I test it with Photoshop CS6. all works fine. You can do almost all functions and parametrize them.

JS code is not small, so to convert it manualy you need to spend a lot of time.
I created an software that do it within one click.

You can download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/js2cconverterphotoshopscript/

Hope it will be useful